# CORBA COS Naming Service Storage

Tags: java, object, naming, corba

i am using the Persistent COS Naming service for binding objects in Java IDL .

By the feature of Persistent Naming service ,

even after you restart 
either Server application 
or

orbd

your Naming graph is intact  on naming service so client can still access the object and its operations (methods) 
I referred this  [COS Naming](http://goo.gl/laEqy)

So my question is the state of the object is stored in naming sevice or object reference itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. It is up to you to persist your object. The thing in the Naming Service is only a reference.

Comment: Great ! Can you tell me where exactly objects are stored??
in the Server app VM,  which i wrote and from where i am instantiated or somewhere else??

Comment: @this-abhi Objects are stored in the JVM that creates them. They're your objects, they don't go anywhere magic.